# Resize ALL images in WebView with Text Autosizing

Tags: image, webview, resize, width

I have a webview set up as:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.display_post_activity_content);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            wv.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
        } else {
            wv.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
        }
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

`content` is static HTML, with some inline CSS. No JavaScript.
This does a wonderful job of text wrapping. It also resizes larger images to fit the screen width.

However, there are some inline images that are smaller than device width. The text wraps around these.

I want it to resize all images (even small ones) to width (keeping Aspect Ratio). Is it possible to achieve that using WebView?
I can do this with `Html.fromHtml()` and `ImageGetter`, but performance with `WebView` is way better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved this one myself:

```java
// Content to be rendered
content = "<p>Some Html </p> with <img></img> tags";

// Set width and height
content = content.replace("<img", "<img height=\"auto\" width=\"100%\" ");

// Render
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

and Voila, full width images with preserved Aspect Ratios!